# Can you use a Spelljammer ship to get to Ravenloft?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, ravenloft, spelljammer

This is an insane question, I know. But it's one that's been bugging me for at least half my 33-year life. :)

I love both the Spelljammer and Ravenloft settings of AD&D 2nd Edition. One of the key tenets of Spelljammer was that you could "sail" (for lack of a better word) to any other D&D universe setting, or to any other setting of the DM's choosing, as long as you had a spellcaster capable of operating the helm.

So I always wondered, within the mythos of the Phlogiston and the spheres, could you Spelljam to Ravenloft? Did Ravenloft exist as a sphere, or was it only accessible when the mists opened?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Complete Spacefarer's Handbook talks a bit about integrating Ravenloft into Spelljammer. It explicitely states that Ravenloft does not exist in a crystal sphere and may not be reached through the Phlogiston. The Mists, however, sometimes reach into wildspace and can trap a spelljamming vessel. Those become trapped in the Demiplane of Dread and have no means to escape through the use of a spelljamming ship.

Comment: So its a one-way ticket?

Comment: @Toby Yep! Just like every other means of transit to that bad place. On the other hand, the ship may have all kinds of fun sailing between domains (if allowed by the mists...) or... gradually become its own domain.

Comment: And if it became its own domain, with its captain (or someone) as its Dark Lord, it could easily be allowed to travel the spheres... but its Lord would never be able to leave the ship, his prison. Never, ever. Everyone else, yes. Imagine the stories.

Answer (score 16):

That answer is obvious.

Yes, because it would be awesome.

But leaving again would have to be tremendously hard, like the goal of a long adventure arc. If it was easy to get out, it wouldn't really be Ravenloft anymore, would it.

Comment: Rule of Cool is always the preferred answer. +1

Comment: "Yes, because it would be awesome." is pretty much *the* defining rule for adjudicating RPGs, for me.

Comment: I agree, but I have a friend who is no longer interested in RPGs as a direct result of the importance of "Yes, because it would be awesome" in contemporary theories of RPG design.

Answer (score 8):

Ravenloft was the "Demiplane of Dread" -demiplanes being miniatures worlds that exist in the fog of the Ethereal Plane (not the Prime Material Plane, that is the main "universe" which had Crystal Spheres in it).
It would be easy to imagine that there could be a crystal sphere somewhere which had a permanent portal to Ravenloft, though. I imagine it would cause alot of "and no one has ever returned from the Galaxy of Terror" type stories around the local asteroid.

Answer (score 4):

Ravenloft is a demi-plane in the Ethereal Plane. Spelljammer takes place in the phlogiston and the crystal spheres of the Prime Material plane.

So you can steal Vecna's Rift-Spanner—a large magical construct—increase its payload to one tonne, and install a Minor Helm or Lifejammer. Use it to create a rift in reality between the Prime Material and Ravenloft, then fly it as a "spelljammer ship" to Ravenloft.

Easier said than done, but hey, it's D&D.

Answer (score 3):

It's a one-way trip. The mists grab you from the phlogiston, and land you in the demi-plane as usual.

Exiting, however...

And, once there, the powers should make certain that weather prevents departure...

Answer (score 1):

The Demiplane of Dread can reach any prime material zone. But in counting the "Karmic/septic separation" reasoning behind Ravenloft's existence, valid reasons are slim with regard to barring the one way diode funneling of PC action from anywhere and any dimension. The reason you do not see immortals routinely routing annoying enemies to the plane, is because the plane itself tends to loop such interlopers in themselves. The gods remain silent on the subject and the Demiplane remains uncommon knowledge for good reason.

Note that in more than one release, the cries of the followers of gods of good often fall upon deaf ears. The justification of a place that is free of any danger of the mists would indeed require reasoning of powers beyond godhood to the level of dimensional existence itself.

Yes, the roach motel is open.